# Can we get a better visited color on MDA?

Tags: feature-request, design, meta

In the theme on Meta Drupal Answers, the color on an anchor is

```
a { color: #a69635 }
```

The visited state is

```
a:visited { color: #6c5f16 }
```

In body copy inside questions / answers, the color is

```
body { color: #444 }
```

The difference between `body` and `a:visited` is *really* subtle:

> [image]

Can we get a different color to let visited links stand out more?